# jquery - live - ajax - success issue

Tags: jquery

I have a table in a php file:

```
<table>
for($x=0;$x<$total;$x++) {
  <tr>
    <td><span id="utype-<?=$array[$x]['unique_id']?>">ADMIN</span></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="changeType" class="<?=$array[$x]['unique_id']?>">Change User Type<a/></td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var curID;

  $('#changeType').live('click', function(){

     curID = $(this).attr('class');

     $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'actions.php?mc=utype',
              data: {
                  did:curID
              },
              success:function(msg) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(msg);
                $('#utype-'+curID).empty().append(json.newType);
                alert('Account changed!');
              },
              error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert('xhr status: '+xhr.status + '\n Error:'+ thrownError);
              }  
     });
  });
});
```

Problem:

The span with id utype is changed while the alert button is there but after clicking OK button the span value will display back the original value.

Example:
   While the alert is still there the ADMIN value is changed to REGULAR but after clicking ok button it goes back to ADMIN.

Question:
   I'd like to ask help on why it goes back to the original value and how to fix it.  Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that after pressing "ok", your table does a "POST" or refresh.  Which means that the php page goes off to retrieve the data again.

If this is the case then you've not saved the value after the ajax post event properly.

Take a look at the save request and make sure the data in $[array] has changed.